# 404 error in wordpress when trying to access a plugin script

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a wordpress plugin in which i use ajax scripting to call an inner script that saves files to local server.  This worked fine in all cases I worked on. But now in a new server, when i try to call the plugin helper url through an ajax call, it results in 404 error - implying that the target plugin script called by the ajax is not available - the url is [**here**](http://mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/add/upload.php)

I understand this is due to some url redirection process in the .htaccess file, but iam unable to resolve it. Without this ajax call working, I am in grave issue.

Below are the contents of my htaccess file which is present in public_html folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If you could suggest a way to exclude my script from the htaccess redirection so that the ajax call works inside my plugin script, it would be really great.

Thanks,
Anuja

Comment: These .htaccess directives are not causing the problem, that's the usual WP rule-set. Try comparing the actual path to the script `wp-content/plugins/myplugin/add/upload.php` with the previous one to see if there is any difference and adjust the calling code accordingly, if needed.

Comment: Hi Faa, thanks for the advice. But what do you mean by comparing the path to the script with the previous one?? what is the previous one?

Comment: You mention this is a new server so the previous one was the path in the old server.

Comment: ok the issue is when i try ajax calling the url in the new server, the return response is "404 Page not found, Something went wrong" with the entire theme of the wordpress.  The script is being treated as a page and is not accessible by itself, some redirection makes it appear as a different url and the response is page not found. Please suggest